# update selected data in mysql in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

how to update selected data in mysql in c#? 
this is my code when i press button2 . all data "jumlah_product" minus two.
i want to make just minus two "jumlah_product" in selected data.

```
 private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=maindata;Uid=root;pwd=firmandoang;";
        string Query = "select * from maindata.product_database where idproduct = '" + this.textBox1.Text + "'  OR namaproduct LIKE '" + this.textBox1.Text + "'";


        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);

        MySqlDataReader myReader;

        conn.Open();
        myReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        try
        {

            if (myReader.Read())
            {

                DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();


                  row.Cells[1].Value = myReader.GetString("namaproduct");
                  row.Cells[2].Value = myReader.GetString("hargaproduct");
                  int count = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

                  int price = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value);

                  row.Cells[3].Value = count;


                  row.Cells[4].Value = price *= count;
                  dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

                  string update = "UPDATE maindata.product_database SET jumlah_product=(jumlah_product - '" + count + "')";
                  MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(update, conn);
                  MySqlDataReader reader;
                  myReader.Close();
                 reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                  reader.Close();

                conn.Close();





            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Data ");
            }
```

sorry for bad english .  I hope you understand :)

Comment: first use SELECT to get JUMLAH_PRODUCT, then minus 2, then UPDATE using new value (already minus 2)

Comment: You would use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` to execute the UPDATE query.